# Sitefinity 10 - .NET Framework 4.7.1 Support

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

Does Sitefinity support targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1?  If not, what versions of the .NET Framework does it support? I am currently running Sitefinity 10.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can build the solution against .NET 4.7.

Sitefinity 10.1 seems to not have the issue as the older versions do:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/sitefinity-and-net-4-7-compatibility-issues

Sitefinity 11 assemblies will be built on .NET 4.7, coming out in the spring (if you are in the northern hemisphere anyway)

https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-filipov-blog/2017/12/20/support-for-.net-4.7-coming-to-sitefinity-11